# React-Native TSLint config usefull to fix performance issues

Tags: typescript, react-native, tslint

Like in the topic, do you have and can share tslint config which can help me to find potential performance issues in react-native app? Which rules might be helpful?

Comment: the react tslint config from palantir is quite good: https://github.com/palantir/tslint-react